# Inner join with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a query as follows and it gives me a error
my query in model is

```
$query = $this->db->select('SELECT AV.Ad_ID, AV.Title, AV.Price, LT1.Listing')
              ->from('ad_vehicle')
              ->join('ref_listing_type', 'ad_vehicle.Listing_Type_ID = ref_listing_type.Listing_ID', 'inner')
              ->where('ad_vehicle.Created_By', 1)
              ->get();
var_dump($query);
return $query->result_array();
```

and my error is

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.Ad_ID, `AV`.`Title`, `AV`.`Price`, `LT1`.`Listing` FROM
>   (`ad_vehicle`) INNER JO' at line 1

```
SELECT `SELECT` AV.Ad_ID, `AV`.`Title`, `AV`.`Price`, `LT1`.`Listing`
FROM (`ad_vehicle`) 
INNER JOIN `ref_listing_type` ON `ad_vehicle`.`Listing_Type_ID` = `ref_listing_type`.`Listing_ID` 
WHERE `ad_vehicle`.`Created_By` = 1
```

Filename: C:\wamp\www\DoolalyJobsBackup\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `select()`   to

```
 $query = $this->db->select('AV.Ad_ID, AV.Title, AV.Price, LT1.Listing')
```

Using active record's `select()` will automatically adds a `SELECT`  keyword you don't need to add again in your query,Also in your query you have used short aliases for the tables but you haven't assign them

```
$this->db->select('AV.Ad_ID, AV.Title, AV.Price, LT1.Listing')
              ->from('ad_vehicle AV')
              ->join('ref_listing_type LT1', 'AV.Listing_Type_ID = LT1.Listing_ID', 'inner')
              ->where('AV.Created_By', 1)
              ->get();
```

Comment: thanx buddy i solve this but i posted another question plz help or mail me ur id omkarhendre89@gmail.com